# Add an another attribute to an existing List in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, nested-lists

I have been trying many ways to add an `isChecked: false` attribute to every list inside the `_filterOptions` List in my Flutter Project. I couldn't find any solution to this. If there is any solution I am happy to see it.

```
List<dynamic> _filters = [];
List<List<dynamic>> _filterOptions =[];
var filters =
    await json.decode(data)["getProductsByStore"]["aggregations"];
    for(int i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
      _filters.add(filters[i]["label"]);
      _filterOptions.add(filters[i]["options"]);

    }
    //print(filters[0]["options"]);
    //print(_filters);
    print(_filterOptions);
```

I am getting this kind of nested list when printed and I want to add the attribute to every list.
[image]

as an example:
[[{count: 3, label: 30-40, value: 30_40, isChecked:false}], [{count: 2, label: Bagged , value: 50, isChecked:false},{...},{...}...]]

Comment: Why not just wrap `_filterOptions` with another custom class object that has `isChecked` parameter?

Comment: Can you show the implementation with a code snippet?

Comment: I've showed it in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Model class with your data and bool isChecked

```
class ModelClass{
  String? label;
  int? count;
  List? options;
  bool? isChecked;

  ModelClass({this.label, this.count , this.options, this.isChecked = false});

  ModelClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    label = json['label'];
    count = json['count'];
    options = json['options'];
  }

}
```

then you can add data like below code

```
 List<ModelClass> list = [];

  void function()async{
    List<dynamic> _filters = [];
    List<List<dynamic>?> _filterOptions =[];
    var filters =
        await json.decode(data)["getProductsByStore"]["aggregations"];
    for(int i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
      ModelClass modelClass = ModelClass.fromJson(filters[i]);
      list.add(modelClass);

      _filters.add(modelClass.label);
      _filterOptions.add(modelClass.options);

    }
    print(list[0].options);
    print(list[0].isChecked);

  }
```

if you want to modify isChecked for some specific index

```
list[0].isChecked = false;
```

Comment: I want to add `isChecked` property inside the _filterOptions(data) list this is the problem I have facing. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: You could create model class for your whole data and with that add one more variable named isChecked that might solve your issue

Comment: I want to add the `isChecked` property inside the options list, so every options list has to show the newly added `isChecked` property. How that can be implemented?

Comment: ohh.. have you tried creating model class for options?

Comment: Yes I have tried but it gives correctly only the `index 0` details

Comment: This answer was really helpful in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines.

```
class YourWrapperClass {
  YourWrapperClass({this.filterOptions = const [], this.isChecked = false});
  List<List<dynamic>> filterOptions;
  bool isChecked;
}

YourWrapperClass filterWrapper = YourWrapperClass(filterOptions: _filterOptions, isChecked: false);
```

And use this wrapper class object whenever ya need to access `_filterOptions`.

But, I would more rather recommend using the WrapperClass on the list elements, like so.

```
class YourWrapperClass {
  YourWrapperClass({this.filterOption = const [], this.filter="", this.isChecked = false});
  List<dynamic> filterOption;
  dynamic filter;
  bool isChecked;
}
List<YourWrapperClass> list = [];
var filters =
    await json.decode(data)["getProductsByStore"]["aggregations"];
    for(int i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
      list.add(YourWrapperClass(filterOption:filters[i]["options"], filter:filters[i]["label"], isChecked=false));
      _filterOptions.add(filters[i]["options"]);

    }
```

Comment: I want to add `isChecked` property inside the `_filterOptions` list this is the probelm I have facing. Do you have any idea on that.